# real time inference on Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, spark-streaming

[image]

I'm trying to run real-time inference on a spark structured stream, first I trained the model

#model_creation

```
model.fit()
model.predict([  33.26,   68.51, 1012.49,   52.68])
```

#create spark df from kafka stream

```
df = spark.readstream.format("kafka").....
```

#inference

```
def predict(input):   
        #extract json from input and conver to list of doubles    
        #model.predict(input_array)   
        #result = model.predict(input_list)   
        #return result
spark.udf.register("lr_predict", predict ,StringType()) 
df3 = df2.withColumn('predict_response',predict(col('value')))

display(df3)
```

I'm not sure how to extract the json input from sql spark dataframe and run it in model, I've been trying things since yesterday nothing seem to  stick.

Comment: please provide the `printSchema` for the df  also , please mention what input data type your `model.predict` expects

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
def predict(input):
""" I am creating the function with following assumptions 
 please tell me if those are not correct 
the model outputs a string value 
the model need numeric data type as input 

"""
    #extract json from input and conver to list of doubles    
        #model.predict(input_array)   
        #result = model.predict(input_list)   
        #return result
    input_proccesed=json.loads(input)
    input_features_array=input_proccesed['input']
    ##casting to float just to be sure 
    input_features_array=[float(x) for x in input_features_array]
    #predicting the output
    result= model.predict(input_proccesed['input'])
    return result
##if the output is string like - "GOOD" /"BAD"  the use StringType()
##if the output is numeric like - 0.92 ,1028.384  the use DecimalType()

from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,DecimalType,FloatType,DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,col
lr_prediction=udf(predict,DoubleType())

df3 = df2.withColumn('predict_response_as_double',lr_prediction(col('value')))
lr_prediction=udf(predict,StringType())
df4 = df2.withColumn('predict_response_as_string',lr_prediction(col('value')))
```